# Stoping a Regex String after a certain point

Tags: javascript, regex, hubot

I am trying to get a regex string working, i have been playing around for a few days and seem to be hitting the lovely fu wall.

I need a way to stop the regex from matching after @username

my Regex string looks like this `(app plex) ?(?:@(.*)|)`

so say the input was `app plex @zycore look at this`, the output would be:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-16    `app plex @zycore`
Group 1.    n/a `app plex`
Group 2.    n/a `zycore look at this`
```

what i am trying to do is have it so only zycore is in group 2 and not the text after it, (the @ symbol is removed as it is not needed in the code but is needed in the application running it), it also needs to work with just `app plex` as an input.

i have tried multiple variations and nothing seems to work, i am using regex101.com to test the strings. any help would be appreciated.

i have tried

```
(app plex) ?(?:@(.*)|)
(app plex) ?(?:@(.*)|)[\s]
(app plex) ?(?:@(.*)[\s]|)
```

Comment: Replace `.` with `\S`, see [`(app plex) ?(?:@(\S*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/v8GfzU/2). To ensure you match at least 1 char, replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: Thank you this works for all text after the @username, however it does not pick up app plex as a single command anymore, group 1 now matches to nothing group 2 picks up zycore and nothing else (the desired effect)

Comment: I edited the solution in my comment, sorry. I posted the updated solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(app plex) ?(?:@(\S*))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8GfzU/2/)

**Details**

- `(app plex)` - Group 1: `app plex` substring
- `?` - an optional space
- `(?:@(\S*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matchin 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `@`  - a `@` char
  - `(\S*)` - Group 2: 0+ non-whitespace chars.